# Why does the output contain only 2 values but not the displacement for the entire image?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision

I have been stuck here for sometime now. I cannot understand what am I doing wrong in calculating the displacement vectors along x-axis and y-axis using the [Lucas Kanade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Kanade_method#Concept) method.

I implemented it as given in the above Wikipedia link. Here is what I have done:

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np


    img_a = cv2.imread("./images/1.png",0)
    img_b = cv2.imread("./images/2.png",0)


    # Calculate gradient along x and y axis
    ix = cv2.Sobel(img_a, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize = 3, scale = 1.0/3.0)
    iy = cv2.Sobel(img_a, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize = 3, scale = 1.0/3.0)

    # Calculate temporal difference between the 2 images
    it = img_b - img_a


    ix = ix.flatten()
    iy = iy.flatten()
    it = -it.flatten()

    A = np.vstack((ix, iy)).T


    atai = np.linalg.inv(np.dot(A.T,A))
    atb = np.dot(A.T, it)

    v = np.dot(np.dot(np.linalg.inv(np.dot(A.T,A)),A.T),it)

    print(v)
```

This code runs without an error but it prints an array of 2 values! I had expected the `v` matrix to be of the same size as that of the image. Why does this happen? What am I doing incorrectly?

**PS:** I know there are methods directly available with OpenCV but I want to write this simple algorithm (as also given in the Wikipedia link shared above) myself.

Comment: because there are obly 2 unknowns? Maybe you have to set up such an equation system for each pixel and its neighborhood?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Could you please show a small example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To properly compute the Lucas–Kanade optical flow estimate you need to solve the system of two equations for every pixel, using information from its neighborhood, not for the image as a whole.

This is the recipe (notation refers to that used on [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Kanade_method#Weighted_window)):

1. Compute the image gradient (*A*) for the first image (`ix`, `iy` in the OP) using any method (Sobel is OK, I prefer Gaussian derivatives; note that it is important to apply the right scaling in Sobel: 1/8).

   ```
    ix = cv2.Sobel(img_a, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize = 3, scale = 1.0/8.0)
    iy = cv2.Sobel(img_a, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize = 3, scale = 1.0/8.0)
   ```
2. Compute the structure tensor (*A<sup>T</sup>WA*): `Axx = ix * ix`, `Axy = ix * iy`, `Ayy = iy * iy`. Each of these three images must be smoothed with a Gaussian filter (this is the windowing). For example,

   ```
   Axx = cv2.GaussianBlur(ix * ix, (0,0), 5)
   Axy = cv2.GaussianBlur(ix * iy, (0,0), 5)
   Ayy = cv2.GaussianBlur(iy * iy, (0,0), 5)
   ```

   These three images together form the structure tensor, which is a 2x2 symmetric matrix at each pixel. For a pixel at `(i,j)`, the matrix is:

   ```
   |  Axx(i,j)  Axy(i,j)  |
   |  Axy(i,j)  Ayy(i,j)  |
   ```
3. Compute the temporal gradient (*b*) by subtracting the two images (`it` in the OP).

   ```
   it = img_b - img_a
   ```
4. Compute *A<sup>T</sup>Wb*: `Abx = ix * it`, `Aby = iy * it`, and smooth these two images with the same Gaussian filter as above.

   ```
   Abx = cv2.GaussianBlur(ix * it, (0,0), 5)
   Aby = cv2.GaussianBlur(iy * it, (0,0), 5)
   ```
5. Compute the inverse of *A<sup>T</sup>WA* (a symmetric positive-definite matrix) and multiply by *A<sup>T</sup>Wb*. Note that this inverse is of the 2x2 matrix at each pixel, not of the images as a whole. You can write this out as a set of simple arithmetic operations on the images `Axx`, `Axy`, `Ayy`, `Abx` and `Aby`.

   The inverse of the matrix *A<sup>T</sup>WA* is given by:

   ```
   |  Ayy -Axy  |  
   | -Axy  Axx  | / ( Axx*Ayy - Axy*Axy )
   ```

   so you can write the solution as

   ```
   norm = Axx*Ayy - Axy*Axy
   vx = ( Ayy * Abx - Axy * Aby ) / norm
   vy = ( Axx * Aby - Axy * Abx ) / norm
   ```

   If the image is natural, it will have at least a tiny bit of noise, and `norm` will not have zeros. But for artificial images `norm` could have zeros, meaning you can't divide by it. Simply adding a small value to it will avoid division by zero errors: `norm += 1e-6`.

The size of the Gaussian filter is chosen as a compromise between precision and allowed motion speed: a larger filter will yield less precise results, but will work with larger shifts between images.

Typically, the `vx` and `vy` is only evaluated where the two eigenvalues of the matrix *A<sup>T</sup>WA* are sufficiently large (if at least one is small, the result is inaccurate or possibly wrong).

---

Using [DIPlib](https://diplib.org) (disclosure: I'm an author) this is all very easy because it supports images with a matrix at each pixel. You would do this as follows:

```
import diplib as dip

img_a = dip.ImageRead("./images/1.png")
img_b = dip.ImageRead("./images/2.png")

A = dip.Gradient(img_a, [1.0])
b = img_b - img_a
ATA = dip.Gauss(A * dip.Transpose(A), [5.0])
ATb = dip.Gauss(A * b, [5.0])
v = dip.Inverse(ATA) * ATb
```

Comment: I got that to work. Thank you. I read that, "LK only works for small displacements with respect to the gradients." Would you have some explanation for this?

Comment: @Sophia: It works for small displacements with respect to the Gaussian smoothing. That is your window. If an object inside the window moves out of the window in the second image, there is no way you could possibly find a correspondence. You need to see the same features within the window in the two images. Does that make sense?

Comment: Okay! You have written that, "a larger filter will yield less precise results". Could you also clarify this?

Comment: @Sophia: If two objects are moving in different directions, and your window so large enough to see both movements at the same time, the movement estimate at that point will be the average of the two movements. You need a smaller filter to distinguish the two movements. This is what I meant with "precise".